# Warning: The provided `src` attribute is an unsupported type ImageUrlBuilder. This value must be coerced to a string before before using it here

Tags: javascript, html, image, next.js, sanity

I am trying to build an app with Sanity and Nextjs using a tutorial. However when I do `npm run dev` I get this error while compiling regarding the images, I have clipped off the exhaustive error list but here it is:
`

```
Warning: The provided `src` attribute is an unsupported type ImageUrlBuilder. This value must be coerced to a string before before using it here.
    at img
    at div
    at HeroBanner (webpack-internal:///./components/HeroBanner.jsx:16:3)
    at Home (webpack-internal:///./pages/index.js:16:3)
    at App (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.js:17:3)
    at StyleRegistry (C:\Users\doguk\Desktop\ecommercetest\e-commerce\node_modules\styled-jsx\dist\index\index.js:449:36)    
    at PathnameContextProviderAdapter (C:\Users\doguk\Desktop\ecommercetest\e-commerce\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\adapters.js:60:11)
    at AppContainer (C:\Users\doguk\Desktop\ecommercetest\e-commerce\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:289:29)
    at AppContainerWithIsomorphicFiberStructure (C:\Users\doguk\Desktop\ecommercetest\e-commerce\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:325:57)
    at renderElement (C:\Users\doguk\Desktop\ecommercetest\e-commerce\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5952:5) {
  page: '/'
}
Warning: The provided `src` attribute is an unsupported type ImageUrlBuilder. This value must be coerced to a string before before using it here.
    at img
    at div
    at HeroBanner (webpack-internal:///./components/HeroBanner.jsx:16:3)
    at Home (webpack-internal:///./pages/index.js:16:3)
    at App (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.js:17:3)
    at StyleRegistry (C:\Users\doguk\Desktop\ecommercetest\e-commerce\node_modules\styled-jsx\dist\index\index.js:449:36)    
    
Warning: The provided `src` attribute is an unsupported type ImageUrlBuilder. This value must be coerced to a string before before using it here.
    at img
    at div
    at HeroBanner (webpack-internal:///./components/HeroBanner.jsx:16:3)
    at Home (webpack-internal:///./pages/index.js:16:3)
    at AppContainer (C:\Users\doguk\Desktop\ecommercetest\e-commerce\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:289:29)
    at AppContainerWithIsomorphicFiberStructure (C:\Users\doguk\Desktop\ecommercetest\e-commerce\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:325:57)
    at div
    at Body (C:\Users\doguk\Desktop\ecommercetest\e-commerce\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:612:21)
    at renderElement (C:\Users\doguk\Desktop\ecommercetest\e-commerce\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5952:5) {
  page: '/'
}
```

`

I tried a bit but I couldn't figure out what was I supposed to do. I still get the same error. I can't display the page this way.

Comment: You should share the part of code where imageBuilder is used

Comment: In ../lib/client.js directory, it is: `import sanityClient from "@sanity/client";
import imageUrlBuilder from "@sanity/image-url";

export const client = sanityClient ({
    projectId: 'thnxtwb8',
    dataset: 'production',
    apiVersion: '2022-11-16',
    useCdn: true,
    token: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_TOKEN
});

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);

export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image
(source);`

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the fact that you are trying to navigate to another product **with no additional images**, while you have **selected any of additional images of the first one**.
This forces the refreshed page to display an product's additional image that **does not exist** and the page results in error.
The best option to solve this problem is to **reset the view of the selected image to 0 on page reload**, or create additional images to match the number of extra photos of other products.